# HP LaserJet 1320 - all pages blank

Tags: printer, laser-printer

HP LaserJet 1320 abruptly stopped printing anything–all pages come out blank.

- The toner cartridge was replaced about three weeks ago.  There was never any fading or streaking of toner; it went from normal printing to nothing between one print job and the next.  The toner cartridge is the manufacturer recommended HP 49x.
- All status lights are normal.  Green 'ready' is default; send a print job and it flashes 'receiving data'; an appropriate number of sheets of paper go through, but all are completely blank.
- The printer is connected to a Mac (10.11.6) via USB, but the pages come out blank whether printing from the locally attached Mac, other computers on the network, or the printer's self-test page.

Fixes attempted:

- Removing and re-inserting the toner cartridge.
- Cleaning contacts (dry cloth) on both toner cartridge and printer.
- Factory reset: power-on while depressing green 'go' button; wait ten seconds and release.

Is there anything more I can do to troubleshoot this printer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whether you can do more depends on what risks you subject yourself to - this quickly devolves into "no user serviceable parts" land. There's high voltage, there's invisible laser light... The official company response it to take it to a qualified service center, and that quickly exceeds the cost of a new printer. Either is cheaper than harming or killing yourself, of course.

My gut reaction to totally blank pages all of a sudden is that some annoying plastic part in the chain that opens the laser shutter has broken, as I've had this happen on other HP LaserJets (not 1320's, I don't have one of those.)

The other potential cause (but I've never seen this one personally) is that the laser/LED or driver (laser/LED power supply) has failed.